# My door closes first on the bottom of the door and leaves a gap on the top half of the door once it is closed

Tags: doors

I recently hung a door that was in an old door frame into a new door frame and the door closes unevenly. It will close on the bottom part of the door first then the top half cant close because the bottom half is closed. This leaves a gap in the top part of the door, in the old door frame the door closes perfectly. I looked at the hinges and they are all straight and in line with each other.

Comment: the new or old slab could be bent, and the hinge alignment for one does not work for the other?

Comment: The door slab could not be bent because in the old door frame it was in, it closed perfectly. The hinges seem straight and aligned with one another.

Comment: doorstop and hinges may require different alignment, definitely on the lock side. are you able to move jambs/stops in the new frame?

Comment: I cannot take remove the door jamb from the old frame this door was in. The old jamb is being used. I think my problem has something to do with the hinges or how the hinges were put onto the door. But everything looks straight and aligned. I don't know what I am missing here.

Comment: 3 hinges? remove middle and bottom, leave top. Close door, support with wedges, and nudge as needed to close the gap as best as possible. You'll have to move the jamb (if possible) or door stop to close remaining gap, since the slab is a given. Mark where and how much to move. May have to re-wedge the jamb, which requires removing any door casing. Picture?

Comment: The door could be warped and the shutting strip was fitted to hide that.